# string literal parsing requires a space to work

Tags: typescript, types

Let's say I have these string literal types.

```
type VarType = 'vec2' | 'vec3' | 'vec4'
type Src = 'vec2 abc;'
```

The goal here is to parse the type `vec2` and the name `abc` at the type level. And keep in mind that whitespace could expansive (multiple spaces, new lines and/or tabs).

So this would also need to parsed similarly:

```
type Src2 = '  vec3\n\t def\n ;'
```

So to start, I want to look for the `VarType` and then send the rest of the string literal on for further processing (trimming whitespace, looking for the next things, etc.)

But we already start to have problems:

```
type TestA = Src extends `${infer U extends VarType}${string}` ? U : false
// expected: 'vec2'
// actual:   'vec2' | 'vec3' | 'vec4'
```

Here, I'd expect `U` to be inferred specifically as what's in the string, and `${string}` should match the rest of the string type that beings with a space. But it fails to infer and returns the constraint instead.

But if a space is added between, it works as expected:

```
type TestB = Src extends `${infer U extends VarType} ${string}` ? U : false
// expected: 'vec2'
// actual:   'vec2'
```

Why?

Shouldn't typescript be able to figure out that `${string}` starts with a space here?

---

Interestingly, if I change the `${string}` to an `${infer Tail}`, then it *fails* to match at all.

```
type TestC = Src extends `${infer U extends VarType}${infer Tail}`
  ? [U, Tail] : false
// expected: ['vec2', ' abc;']
// actual:   false
```

I don't understand why making part of a conditional type `infer` should change the success to a failure. The matching seems like it should be independent of the ability to infer types from that match.

And again, adding the space fixes it:

```
type TestD = Src extends `${infer U extends VarType} ${infer Tail}`
  ? [U, Tail] : false
// expected: ['vec2', 'abc;']
// actual:   ['vec2', 'abc;']
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgJwCrmgXigcgG4QMYBMmUAPlrngMzFk74AsmAUKJFAMoJ5QZ2FRwARngDczVtE79eUKBUoAdAHYLgUACYQAZmKgB6PVGAALAJYBnKBagB3YyCjHEeAPbrTSgOYCo5sHDxoGxclTDVghABrADomJgMoADkXX39Aq0tBOHVYiSgkCHNgAEEeDi4oCAAPYAgldUsAAwASAG8PLQgEKABVSpq6hthEFEgAXzaihA9PMcaoAH5eqAAuKC04ABtzCHjDasg8WvU1viI9gSOAVy212TOacnxqUie8RjiE9jToLVMqwpWYAsVD5QrAABCZSk-Vq9SabQ6XWW1ThQ3gyFQYygk2A0y8c0WyzWG22uwSB3wx1OFHOCQCwBumzub3OcQuSO6wDgpk2AksNggm02n0MyVSAWg1iyORBbAKRQAwtCKqjBgj2kpOt0+mr4cNMeNEVrkUgeXy9UMpjNCUsANo9AA0+XNAF1VustjsLpSjhATlA7Q9ncQhKJMK6LgymSzSd64nkFcAACIq7iWjWclEDfUY0YQbHG7Uu3m2wNOkubd0kr3k-ZVQ7UwPBrBhsSR+nXW6yZu0zAhtsRphAA)

Comment: This is new functionality since TS4.7 so I don't see a huge amount of stuff about it to come up with an authoritative answer.  My *guess* is that `${infer X extends Y}${string}` has two "holes" next right next to each other and therefore the first one will be inferred as a single character to start with, then this fails and you get other weird fallback behavior.  It *could* be a bug or design limitation that this happens, but unless someone (probably not me) files a github issue about it I wouldn't know for certain.  I'll keep looking for a bit

Comment: Like, [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47048#issuecomment-1010327493) plus [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49839) is the closest I could get for a source for now. Not sure if that suffices in an answer or you need something more targeted to this particular situation

Comment: Fascinating, though annoying. "In general, immediately adjacent placeholders are really only useful for taking strings apart one character at a time." sheds some light on things. I'm sure it can be worked around, but those solutions will be much more cumbersome. Thanks @jcalz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) a *placeholder* is any type position that requires inference to match.  This happens for `infer` such as in `` `${infer X}` `` or `` `${infer Y extends Z}` ``.  It also happens for "pattern" template literals such as in `` `${string}` `` or `` `${number}` ``, as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598).

One feature, and limitation, of TypeScript is when a placeholder is followed immediately by another placeholder, as in `` `${string}${string}` `` or `` `ab${infer Y extends Z}${number}cd` ``, that first placeholder is going to match a single character, no matter what.

It's a feature because it lets you parse a string character-by-character recursively via a constructs like `` T extends `${infer F}${infer R}` ? ... : ... `` where `F` is the first character of `T` and `R` is the rest of `T`.  (If `F` could match less than one or more than one character, then this sort of parsing would be impossible, or at least *much* more complicated).

And it's a limitation because of the sort of behavior you're running into here; there's no good way to get the first placeholder to match some variable-length string.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#47048](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47048#issuecomment-1010327493) for more information.

---

If you add a space between two placeholders, they are no longer immediately adjacent, and this behavior stops happening.  This explains why you get different behavior with and without a space, although it doesn't actually explain the particular thing you do see.  After all, `TestA` doesn't evaluate to a single character, it evaluates to `VarType`.  Why?

I suspect that first `U` is inferred as a single character, which fails to match the [`extends VarType` constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#extends-constraints-on-infer-type-variables).  So inference fails.  Then, when inference fails, type variables fall back to their constraints.  So `U` falls back to `VarType`.  Now the compiler tries to match `Src` against `` `${VarType}${string}` ``, which *succeeds*.  And you get the weird behavior you're seeing here.  The inference neither completely succeeds (where `TestA` is `"vec2"`) nor completely fails (where `TestA` is `false`); instead you get this in-between thing.  This is very similar to the issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#49839](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49839), which is marked as a bug... although it's also marked as "Cursed?" which means something like "this isn't good but the alternatives might be even worse", so I wouldn't expect to see a change anytime soon.

---

Sometimes when I have situations like this I can split the single two-placeholder check into two one-placeholder checks:

```
type TestA = Src extends `${VarType}${infer R}` ?
    Src extends `${infer U}${R}` ? U : never : false
// type TestA = "vec2"
```

This may or may not work for your use case.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgJwCrmgXigcgG4QMYBMmUAPlrngMzFk74AsmAUKJFAMoJ5QZ2FRwARngDczFqihIIAZ2ABBHhy5QIAD2AQAdgBMZUAAYASAN7xkqAL6mAlloBmEBFABKlg1AD8TKL+Xd1TV19YxM7R2cAVWsTNw9PKEioAC4oLQhcZ1T7OAAbGQgmAHoiqFZoaTlFDAAiCgIapiA)