# How does typescript simplify writing for getting template string content?

Tags: typescript

When using a template string, it is very simple if I take the characters from left to right

```js
type str = "abcd"
// I can use this code to get "a" and "bcd" at one time
type ret = str extends `${infer first}${infer rest}` ? `${first}${rest}` : str;
```

But if the first element I want to get isn't a single character then it gets a little more complicated

```js
type str2 = "123c"
type t2 = "a" | "b" | "c"

type ret2 =
    str2 extends `${infer before}${t2}` ?
    (
        str2 extends `${before}${infer after}` ?
        (
            // I got before and after here, but this step seems to be a lot of redundancy
        )
        :
        (
            never
        )
    )
    :
    (
        never
    )
```

[code link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAzsBOUC8UBEBDAZjAJt9ARgMaoBQpokU8EwysCUEAHsBAHY4xQAGAJAG8Alu0wREmIfDgBfQSLGIasnlAD8vQZOnA5A5btUAuBvADc5CuGhx4AJnqpiOQiStVgDlBlRQAPmgEvgGobu7QNJ7IpFCxpg4sbJzc-MKi4lAEEJgA9jR6njKqajFxABSlcXG2CawcXJoCWbn58umIWGzwReqVVVAV-UNQAPQjUIAU6oCb8YAziYCIRoDp+oAMSoBhcs150IAxKlCd4gA0UIBi8oD0ZlOAAHKAptaA0O6A7rGApuaAEfqAWJqAmvJ9wzuYXe9xAJQ-sSMAIGwKq7AgADdxMD-lVYXEgVVBsNwVD4H1fkA)

The question is whether 123 and c can be obtained at one time in the second case?

Comment: I think may be a duplicate of this question I asked a while back: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74987244/string-literal-parsing-requires-a-space-to-work. Short answer is that without a delimiter between the inferred strings, you'll need to do it two steps. Which really isn't that bad, in my opinion. In your case that might look like this: https://tsplay.dev/mxy3xW

Comment: @AlexWayne Yes, I'm just saying that it's better to get two contents inside a single step, it cuts down on a layer of unnecessary nesting, I tried writing `str2 extends \`${infer before}${infer after extends t2}\`` and I thought it should work, but in reality it won't work as expected.

Comment: I'm trying to find out if there's a one-step acquisition possibility, which doesn't preclude the answer from being no, or having to wait for official support from the ts team.